# Trying to scrape a table with beautiful soup in python but body is empty

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

First time attempt to scrape a table from a website. My code is below. For some reason the table body is coming up empty. Ideally I'd scrape this website and store the table in a CSV file. I think I may be missing sending a parameter or a delay maybe? I'm unsure.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

source = requests.get("https://www.cmegroup.com/trading/energy/crude-oil/light-sweet-crude.html")
src = source.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(src, features='html.parser')

tables = soup.tbody
print(tables.prettify())
```

Comment: Did you check wether the data you need is dynamically generated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi below code works for me. You need to use selenium to capture the table

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import time
webpage = 'https://www.cmegroup.com/trading/energy/crude-oil/light-sweet-crude.html'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='Your/path/to/chromedriver.exe') 
driver.get(webpage)
time.sleep(15)
html = driver.page_source

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
table = soup.find('table')
table_rows = table.find_all('tr')

res = []
for tr in table_rows:
    td = tr.find_all('td')
    row = [tr.text.strip() for tr in td if tr.text.strip()]
    if row:
        res.append(row)


df = pd.DataFrame(res, columns=["Month", "Charts", "Last","Change","Prior Settle","Open ","High","Low","Volume","Hi / Low Limit","Updated"])
print(df)
driver.quit()
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me after downloading chromedriver. I also went ahead and used the Anaconda interpreter instead. Thank you so much! Next step is to push this data frame to a sql table!

Comment: great to hear that. For pushing the data you can use SqlAlchemy or similar library.
Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

That table you see is being generated / loaded in postprocessing through Javascript code, which the requests module that you're using doesn't support.

Somebody recently recommend to switch to the [requests-html](https://requests.readthedocs.io/projects/requests-html/en/latest/) module instead.